# What roles are available for Azure Container Instances operator

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-identity

I'd like to assign a user assigned manage identity a role in resource group scope for Azure Container Instances related operation, such as list containers in a RG, start or stop an container group, is there any build-in role available for this purpose? I searched in the role list, not find any:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Usually,[to use a managed identity](https://C:%5CUsers%5Cv-sakavya%5CDesktop%5CEnable%20managed%20identity%20in%20container%20group%20-%20Azure%20Container%20Instances%20%7C%20Microsoft%20Docs), that particular identity should have the  access granted to following one or more Azure service resources like **`azure web app`**, ***`azure key vault`***(with access policies or roles), or ***`azure storage account`*** in the subscription.

Select Access control (IAM).

and  Add role assignment

- Select roles , select appropriate role that you want the user identity to
  have.

[image]

- Here i am giving for storage access
- To give storage access select storage blob data reader role or
  contributer role

[image]

- Then select the managed identity and select required user managed
  identity.

[image]

But please **note** that from [***Limitations***: Enable managed identity in container group - Azure Container Instances | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-managed-identity#limitations)

> 1. **Currently you can't use a managed identity in a container group deployed to a virtual network.**
> 2. **Container groups which are running in Azure Virtual Networks do not  support managed identity authentication image pulls with ACR.**

If  system assigned identity is enabled, then the group must have  'Contributor' role in order to have access to a storage account.

**Reference:**
[use-a-managed-identity | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-managed-identity#use-a-managed-identity)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem answer my question.

Comment: The operations are directly not available AFAIK.You may have to  create as custom role to run/stop container instances : see [this](https://i.imgur.com/rPTHDQk.png)